# Looking for AntDesign Component

Tags: antd, react-component

I'm relatively new to React & Web Development and looking to make a [Joplin](https://github.com/laurent22/joplin) clone to learn.

I've been using antdesign, and so far it is fine. I'm looking for a basic component that is a list that you can hover over and select.

[part I can't find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzUzf.png)

The closest I've been able to find is the Database component, but that comes with the column headers which I don't want.
[Database Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5Tep.png)

Perhaps this the kind of thing that you are expected to make yourself, but was wondering if there was a way to find it in antd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are okay with the table component from `AntD`, you can remove the header with the props `showHeader` to false.

You can find more details [here](https://ant.design/components/table/#API).